# Part of my js script not working in my ejs file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

The "if" statement in my ejs file doesn't seem to work.

Here is my .ejs file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>causelist</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Select the causes you want to back.</h1>
 <form action="/causelist" method="post">
  <% cause.forEach(function(cause){ %>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cause" value="<%= cause.CauseId %>" <% if (cause.CauseId===donate.CauseId1 || cause.CauseId===donate.CauseId2 || cause.CauseId===donate.CauseId3 || cause.CauseId===donate.CauseId4 || cause.CauseId===donate.CauseId5) { %> checked <% } %> > <%= cause.CauseName %> <br>
    <% }) %>
    <input type='submit'>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.get which renders the page and sends in values after retrieving from my MySQL DB:

```
app.get('/causelist', ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
connection.query("select * from DonateTo where UserId = "+ req.user.UserId, function(err,rows){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    var donate = rows;
    console.log("donate:"+ donate);
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Causes",function(err,rows){
        var cause = rows;
        console.log("cause:"+ cause);
        res.render('causelist',{cause,donate});
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
    });
});
});
```

I don't understand what I'm missing. 
Note: Except the if statement, the rest of the code works fine. i.e. data being retrieved from my DB is correct.

Comment: which if is your mean?

Comment: The one in my ejs file.

Comment: can you clear your question? what is exactly dont work fine there is two if satatement in your file, the second one is after rendering the html view @IshaanShakunt

Comment: There is only one if statement in my ejs file.

Comment: where did `donate` defined in your loop? it seems undefined

Comment: Donate is sent to the ejs file via the node app.get function.

Comment: you should send `donate[0]` from server side

Comment: But it works when I send cause..Maybe that  is because  of the forEach function? I'll try when I get back home. Thanks for the answer ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you send a json array named `cause` then in `.ejs` file you parse it correctly and take objects from this but `donate` is an json array and if you want get property from its objects you should define which object do you want with `index` so if you want the first object from `donate` you should send it to client like `donate[0]`

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thanks.